# how i gather some data based another column

Tags: python

dataframe:

| id | book |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aBook |
| 1 | bBook |
| 1 | cBook |
| 2 | aBook |
| 2 | bBook |
| 3 | dBook |

what i want:

| id | book |
| --- | --- |
| [1,2] | aBook |
| [1,2] | bBook |
| 1 | cBook |
| 3 | dBook |

is it possible make that happen? book is actually not a string, it is an integer by bookId, I just make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group-by and then aggregate using `list`:

```py
df.groupby('book').agg(list).reset_index()
```

If you have additional features you can then merge back to the original dataframe:

```py
result.merge(df, on='book', suffixes=('s', ''))
```